# Combining a string and integer and printing

Tags: python, list, optimization, printing, iteration

Given the Below Lists:

```
a = ['abc','cde','efg']
b = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[4,5,6]]
```

What is an optimized way to print the output as shown below: 
Looking for an optimized way as in real I have about 100 x 100 elements.
Also keep in mind that each element in b is an integer while in a is a string

```
abc,1,2,3
cde,2,3,4
efg,4,5,6
```

Comment: can you check my answer and let us know if it helped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print in the exact format you specified:

```
print('\n'.join([a[i] + ',' + str(b[i]).strip('[').strip(']').replace(' ','') for i in range(len(a))]))
```

Output:

```
abc,1,2,3
cde,2,3,4
efg,4,5,6
```

100*100 element is a very small number for a python program - any optimization at this scale will probably fail to be significant enough for *us humans* to have noticed. To test:

```
%%timeit
array = np.random.randn(100,100)
print('\n'.join([str(e) for e in array])) # prints like above
```

result:

```
148 ms ± 13.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Also - keep in mind the main bottle neck should be the `print`, not the actual process doing the printing, hence using `zip` or other trick may not work as they don't help the terminal/other stdout capture print fast enough.

Comment: Yes but I have to run like 5000 iterations of 100 x 100 and if each iteration takes like couple seconds the whole program takes like in minutes hence I was concerned

Comment: 100*100 will probably take a 100ms, tested. Also, most of the time is probably taken by `print` itself, because it takes time for stdout to capture and display the characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use `range`,

```
for i in range(len(b)):
    print("{},{}".format(a[i],','.join([str(x) for x in b[i]])))

#output,
abc,1,2,3
cde,2,3,4
efg,4,5,6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `zip()` and `str.join()`:

```
>>> a = ['abc','cde','efg']
>>> b = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[4,5,6]]
>>> print('\n'.join(','.join(map(str, (x, *y))) for x, y in zip(a, b)))
abc,1,2,3
cde,2,3,4
efg,4,5,6
```